# Have an error with AES key after his RSA decryption

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I'm trying to realize hybrid cryptosystem with pycryptodome.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Random.random import getrandbits
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto import Random
import base64
import hashlib
import os

def main():
    setup()
    data = b'12 43 42 46 af'
    key, data = send_data_to_dron(data)
    receive_data(key, data)

class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def pad(self, s):
        return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

    def encrypt(self, message, key, key_size=256):
        message = self.pad(message)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext, key):
        iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
        print(len(key))
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
        return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def receive_data(key, data):
    private_key = RSA.import_key(open("./keys/private1.pem").read())
    dsize = SHA.digest_size
    sentinel = Random.new().read(15+dsize)
    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
    aes_key = cipher.decrypt(key, sentinel)
    print("dec AES key:", aes_key)

    cipher = AESCipher(aes_key)
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(data, key)
    return decrypted

def send_data_to_dron(data):
    key = os.urandom(16)
    print("gen AES key:", key)
    print(len(key))
    cipher = AESCipher(key)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(data, key)

    rsa_public1 = RSA.import_key(open("./keys/public1.pem").read())
    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_public1)
    ecnrypted_aes_key = cipher.encrypt(key)
    return ecnrypted_aes_key, ciphertext

def setup():
    key1 = RSA.generate(2048)
    private_key1 = key1.export_key()
    fileout = open("./keys/private1.pem", mode="wb+")
    fileout.write(private_key1)
    public_key1 = key1.publickey().export_key()
    file_out = open("./keys/public1.pem", "wb+")
    file_out.write(public_key1)

    key2 = RSA.generate(2048)
    private_key2 = key2.export_key()
    fileout = open("./keys/private2.pem", mode="wb+")
    fileout.write(private_key2)
    public_key2 = key2.publickey().export_key()
    file_out = open("./keys/public2.pem", "wb+")
    file_out.write(public_key2)

    send_private("./keys/private1.pem", to='dron')
    send_private("./keys/private2.pem", to='operator')
    send_public("./keys/public1.pem", to='dron')
    send_public("./keys/public2.pem", to='operator')

def send_private(keyfile_path, to='dron'):
    pass

def send_public(keyfile_path, to='dron'):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Have such output:

```
gen AES key: b'A\xef\xc1\xa8\xa1\rf\xb3\xd1\x95\xe4L\xc1.\x16\xa9'<br>
16 (length of generated key)<br>
dec AES key: b'A\xef\xc1\xa8\xa1\rf\xb3\xd1\x95\xe4L\xc1.\x16\xa9'<br>
256 (lenght of decrypted key)<br>
<i>Long traceback</i><br>
ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (256 bytes)<br>
```

I may specialize padding for RSA encrypting, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by my own.

```
def receive_data(key, data):
    ...
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(data, aes_key)#used variable ket instead of aes key
    ...
```

But i think i should leave it here for future users)